# Creating a RDLC List report with data from related tables in Visual studio 2013

Tags: rdlc

How do you create an RDLC list report from data in multiple related tables?
The tablix created for the list can only be bound to one dataset. This will not allow related data from other datasets in the report to be shown.

Do I need to combine the related data into a single table in Visual studio dataset designer and use this as an RDLC dataset?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by joining my related tables in a View, and then used that view in the report as a single table.

Hope this helps! since it's my first answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a public class Event to {get;set;} value ,and use an array or a list to save the items.
If you need more suggestion,let me know,I will try my best to help you.